# Why Are Three Dots In A String Like "..." Considered As 1 Length?

Tags: flutter, dart

Update: The title would be, "Why Are Regular Three Dots Was Considered As Ellipsis By TextEditingController". Because I didn't touch anything out of the dot button

---

I'm controlling the length of TextField with TextEditingController (With this way because I want to guide the user step by step)

```
 if (usernameController.text.length < 3) {
      _showMessage('username'.tr, 'username_min'.tr);
      return;
 }
```

If the input is "`ab...`", then the controller says the length as 3

If the input is "`a...a`", then the controller says the length as 3

If the input is "`...`", then the controller says the length as 1

[image]

[image]

What I am missing?

Comment: There's a difference between `...` (three dots) and the Unicode character 'ellipsis': https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm -- I'm guessing the translation only occurs when the ellipsis is surrounded by spaces on both sides. This represents the Oxford style of ellipsis: https://prowritingaid.com/Ellipsis (under "Style Guide Rules"

Comment: I don't know much about flutter/dart, but it looks like something is combining the three dots into a single ellipsis character (U+2026 HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS)

Comment: I tested in dart pad and it returns as I expected.```void main() {String text1 = 'ab...';
  String text2 = 'a...a';
  String text3 = '...';
  
  print(text1.length);
  print(text2.length);
  print(text3.length);
}```. run this in https://dartpad.dev. I suggest you to print value of your string to see what is it exactly

Comment: If you use macOS it transforms three distinct dot characters `...` into an ellipsis character `…` automatically by default after you type a space character.

Comment: @lepsch Seems this is what happened here. But didn't get `after you type a space character.` You meant this transformation occurred because of my iPhone?

Comment: It transforms on my MacBook after any character actually.

Comment: @lepsch No transformation occurred after typing 3rd dot. You know dots of ellipsis are closer than regular three dots. Maybe this behavior of `TextEditingController` on Flutter side.

Comment: @NastaranMohammadi for better testing, 1) Bind `TextEditingController` and TextField. 2) Type three dots. 3) Acces value of input via the controller.

Comment: @barrycarter, and McGowen:  yes, the regular three dots was somehow interpreted as ellipsis. But I didn't understand what caused it.